# Highlight text as entered by user - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a text paragraph, and an input box. User is going to type same text  in the input box as shown in paragraph.

I want to color highlight the paragraph text as user types it so as to show the progress. I'm not sure how I'd do it in HTML and CSS.

My current thinking is to have some sort of tag (span probably) for every word in the text. And then keep adding a color class as uses enters the text. I'd like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

an example would be some of the typing sites http://www.typingtest.com/

Comment: prehaps some images of examples of what sort of thing you're trying to achieve would help us see the light? But I would say Ajax and CSS?

Comment: Here is a good example, very similar to what I'm trying to do. http://www.typingtest.com/

Comment: Sorry, that link isn't working for me. When you get the link to work an you add it to the question? makes it all clearer to understand, cheers.

Comment: In which case it's simple, turn the text into an array of characters and use a keyboard event to trigger pattern matching between the array and the input string.

Comment: Martin I added it in the question, also in my comment

Comment: If you want to do checks based on every word then just do a splice based on the space character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better used in JavaScript/jQuery. Here is one example implementation

```js
var originalText = $("#user-text").text();

$("textarea").on("keyup", function() {
    var enteredText = $("textarea").val();
    var length = enteredText.length;
    if (originalText.search(enteredText) == 0) {
    $("#user-text").html("<span class='highlight'>" + originalText.slice(0, length) + "</span>" + originalText.slice(length, originalText.length));
    }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>

<p id="user-text">This is a paragraph</p>
```

You want to store the value of the paragraph in a variable outside of the function.

You then want to listen for the `keyup` function and get the input entered by the user. Find if it occurs in the original string, and then change the html of the original string.

We will insert a class for highlighting the typed in input if there is an exact match. We will then append the rest of the string with no styling.